# How to apply different isin for each row of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've got two arrays and want to compare rows. In particular, I want to check for each element in arr2 whether it is among corresponding row in arr1.

Example given

```
arr1 = [[1, 7, 6, 2, 8],
        [1, 5, 4, 8],
        [8, 2, 5]]

arr2 = [[8, 1, 5, 0, 7, 2, 9, 4],
        [0, 1, 8, 5, 3, 4, 7, 9],
        [9, 2, 0, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7]]
```

Expected result for the first row of arr2

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Solution with for-loop

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(arr1)
d2 = pd.DataFrame(arr2)

for y in range(len(arr1)):
    print(d2.iloc[y].isin(d1.iloc[y]).astype(int).tolist())
```

How to do it in pandas without iterating over rows?

Comment: Can you explain the result for the first row, please?

Comment: You could do `df = pd.DataFrame(arr2).T.isin(dict(enumerate(map(set, arr1)))).T.astype("int")`, but that isn't really faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do via list comprehension with one for loop.

```
arr1 = [[1, 7, 6, 2, 8],
        [1, 5, 4, 8],
        [8, 2, 5]]

arr2 = [[8, 1, 5, 0, 7, 2, 9, 4],
        [0, 1, 8, 5, 3, 4, 7, 9],
        [9, 2, 0, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7]] 

[1 if x in arr1[0] else 0 for x in arr2[0]]

#output
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

---

**Pandas** Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame(arr1)
d2 = pd.DataFrame(arr2)
d2.iloc[0].isin(d1.iloc[0]).astype(int).tolist()

#output
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

For all rows:

```
for y in range(len(arr1)):
    print(d2.iloc[y].isin(d1.iloc[y]).astype(int).tolist())

[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: ... and either approach easily extended for all rows, which seems to be the OP intention.

Comment: Is it possible without iterating over rows of arr1?

Comment: Yes, I think we can use apply. I have to see the syntax before I update

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without iterating the rows. `df.isin()` can accept a dictionary in which the keys need to be the column names.

Edit: I just noticed that the below solution is nearly identical to the comment made by Timus

```
pd.DataFrame(arr2).T.isin(dict(enumerate(arr1))).astype(int).T.to_numpy()
```

Also, here is a way with list comprehension:

```
[[int(i in a1) for i in a2] for a1,a2 in zip(arr1,arr2)]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```